# Probability that all red balls are removed before all the blue ones?

Tags: probability

[image]

My thougts:

Let $R$ be number of red balls remaining in the urn and $B$ be number of balls remaining in urn. We want to find $P(R=0 | B > 0)$. By definition, then

$$ \frac{ P(R=0 \cap B > 0 ) }{P(B>0)} $$

Now, $P(B>0) = 1 - P(B=0) = 1 - \frac{ 1}{ {30 \choose 12} } $

but I am stuck on the numerator part. How do we interpret it?

Comment: I’m not sure I agree with this setup. Is your sample space all possible moments in time, or all possible sequences of removals?

Comment: Perhaps a tricky rabbit way:  The probability that all the red balls are removed before the blue ones is precisely when he last ball removed is blue.  And the probability of that is $\frac 13$.

Comment: "Let R be number of red balls remaining in the urn" after how many draws?  this isn't well explained or defined.  Why is $P(B=0) =\frac 1{30 \choose 12}$?  I don't understand that at all and .... ?$12$? where the *heck* did the number $12$ come from?

Comment: The probability that all the red ones are removed before all the blue ones equals the probability that last ball removed is blue $ \frac {1}{3}$

Comment: No problem.  I'll delete mine.

Comment: "but I am stuck on the numerator part. How do we interpret it?"  What do you mean how do we interpret it?  *You* are the one who wrote it.  You interpret it in the exact same meaning that caused you to write it in the first place.  Why *DID* you write it in the first place?

Comment: I was just playing around with the definition of conditional probability and see where it lead me it led me nowhere

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Imagine labeling the balls 1 through 30.  Convince yourself that if the $30!$ ways to remove the balls, that the *last* ball is $k$ is equally likely for any possible $k$.

Then of the $30$ equally likely options the last ball can be, $10$ of them are that the last ball is blue.

So the probability the last ball is blue is $\frac {10}{30} = \frac 13$.

The last ball being blue occurs if and only if all the red balls are removed before all the blue balls.

Comment: I dont understand why last ball blue is same as all red balls removed before blue balls

Comment: @Neymar Think about it.  If the last ball is blue, then all of the red balls occurred before that last ball, and in particular since the last ball is blue there is at least one blue ball (*namely the last one, possibly more*) which occurs after all of the red balls.  On the other hand, if the last ball was red then all of the blue balls must have occurred before the final red ball and none occurred after.

Comment: "I dont understand why last ball blue is same as all red balls removed "  Um.. think about it. If the last ball is blue then all the red balls were removed before the last blue ball was removed.  If the last ball is red than all the red balls were *not* removed before the last blue ball was removed.  That really wasn't meant to be a stumper.